# Change the visibility of a react component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hi the following code should modify the visibility of a react component depending on whether or not a button is clicked, this when a button is clicked the first element  must disappear and I have to appear the second, but this does not happen what is this due to?

**React code:**

```
import React from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";
import image from "../../assets/img/calc.png";
import CalculatorContainer from "./CalculatorDraggable/index";

class DraggableCalculator extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { isCalculatorVisible: false };
  }
  enable() {
    console.log("Make calculator visibile");
    this.setState({
      isCalculatorVisible: true,
    });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <p>
        {this.state.isCalculatorVisible == true ? (
          <CalculatorContainer />
        ) : (
          <p></p>
        )}
        <Container onClick={this.enable}>
          <img
            key={Math.random()}
            src={image}
            alt="help"
            width={120}
            height={220}
            style={{ marginLeft: 20 }}
          />
        </Container>
      </p>
    );
  }
}

export default DraggableCalculator;

const Container = styled.div`
  border-radius: 25px;
  border: 2px solid #73ad21;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;

  /* background-color: var(--cLight2);
  border: 5px solid var(--cMain); */
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-top: 30px;
  margin-right: auto;
  cursor: pointer;

  // @MEDIA TABLET LANDSCAPE
  @media only screen and (min-device-width: 768px) and (max-device-width: 1024px) and (orientation: landscape) {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
  }

  img {
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
  }
`;
```

Comment: I suggest you use functional components instead of class components, this kind of problems cannot happen with functional components and they are significantly easier to work with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the `enable` function doesn't have the `this` of the class component bound to it, it throws an error `TypeError Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'setState')`.

Either bind `this` to it in the constructor

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = { isCalculatorVisible: false };
  this.enable = this.enable.bind(this); // <--
}
```

or convert to an arrow function so it happens automatically

```
enable = () => {
  console.log("Make calculator visible");
  this.setState({
    isCalculatorVisible: true,
  });
}
```

[image: Edit change-the-visibility-of-a-react-component]

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not working because "this" is undefined inside the enable() function. It so because React component (DraggableCalculator, in your case) does not auto-bind its methods to itself.

Hence you have to bind any method yourself inside the constructor, like this for your case:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { isCalculatorVisible: false };

    this.enable = this.enable.bind(this);
}
```